# how to fix SecurityException from class org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTUtils?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint

**I am  trying to Consume Sonar API , During file scanning getting below issue , I have tried sonar community but still struggling to fix...Please anyone help me to resolve this issue**

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTUtils"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:1150)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:905)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1014)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.sonar.java.model.JParser.convert(JParser.java:197)
    at org.sonar.java.model.JParser.parse(JParser.java:165)
    at org.sonar.java.model.JParserConfig$FileByFile.parse(JParserConfig.java:268)
    ... 5 more
```

https://community.sonarsource.com/t/an-exception-occurred-while-running-the-java-custom-rule/58041

Comment: What is your SonarQube version?

Comment: i am using this version<version>9.3.0.51899</version>